# Update with wildcard

Tags: sql-server, replace, wildcard

in need to update all the rows that have sub string like this:
'forcestartpage=xx'and replace it with 'forcestartpage=18'
* there is lots of characters before and after the substring that shouldnt change

tried this, doesnt work:

```
update t_reminderscont
set body = REPLACE (body,'forcestartpage=__','forcestartpage=18')
```

thanks

Comment: Can the "forcestartpage=XX" be repeated more than once on your values?

Comment: Wildcard characters can only be used in conjunction with pattern searching operators/functions such as `LIKE` and `PATINDEX`. a `'_'` in a `REPLACE` will simply be treated as the underscore character, not as a single character wildcard.

Comment: Some example values will greatly help us here too. I *assume* that `forcestartpage` can't have a value greater than 99, and if it's less than 10 it'll have a leading 0 (i.e. `'forcestartpage=08'`)

Comment: no , only one time (forcestartpage=XX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get away with a `STUFF` function:

```
SELECT
    T.body,
    Replaced = STUFF(
        T.Body,                                 -- Insert in T.Body
        CHARINDEX('forcestartpage=', T.Body),   -- ... at the position where 'forcestartpage=' starts
        LEN('forcestartpage=18'),               -- ... while replacing 17 characters
        'forcestartpage=18')                    -- ... the value forcestartpage=18
FROM
    YourTable AS T
WHERE
    T.body LIKE '%forcestartpage=__%' AND
    T.body NOT LIKE '%forcestartpage=18%'
```

However this will only work for the first appearance of the `forcestartpage=` on each row.